# Clicking Windows Calculator buttons with AutoItLibrary for Robot Framework and RIDE

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, ui-automation, autoit

I have Robot Framework, RIDE and AutoItLibrary installed. I want to open an instance of Windows Calculator, click the <kbd>7</kbd> button, keep the window open for a couple of seconds, then close it.

The test case is running and passing, but the <kbd>7</kbd> button does not get clicked. Every step apart from clicking the button is being performed.

The strategy to click <kbd>7</kbd> is via coordinates. Using the AutoIt finder tool the coordinates of the <kbd>7</kbd> button were found. Unfortunately the finder tool does not show the name or ID of controls in the Calculator Window:

[image]

It appears that the coordinates are relative to the entire screen, not the Calculator window. So when an instance of this window is opened it may be at a different location. How can the button be reliably clicked?

Code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           AutoItLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
TC0
    # Opens the Calculator, waits until it is active, keeps it open for 2 seconds, then closes it.
    Run    calc.exe
    Win Wait Active    Calculator
    ControlClick    Calculator    ${EMPTY}    ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow1    left    1    50    350
    BuiltIn.Sleep    2s
    Win Close    Calculator
```

Comment: What's your question? Just getting `7` into the Calculator or interact with a button (in any application), where the FinderTool can't find the control?

Comment: I think what @Christ tell below is that you can change your code by remove `ControlClick    Calculator    ${EMPTY}    ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow1    left    1    50    350` and instead use `Send    7`.

Comment: I have found windows 10 calculator a bit weird to work with using autoit, so if you are just trying to test out some simple code, I would suggest trying something like notepad or the application you are ultimately interested in automating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Scite.exe and paste this code:

```
Run("calc.exe")
WinWaitActive("Calculator")
Send("7")
sleep (2000)
WinClose("Calculator")
```

Comment: What is Scite.exe? Where can I find it?

Comment: Downoad autoit from https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/ and you will find it there!

Comment: It was actually the "Send" command that worked. I didn't try it with Scite.exe, but from within RIDE, as @akane suggested in a comment above.